# Can't find accommodation in Mantova, Italy. Where can I spend the night?

Tags: italy, nightlife

I'm traveling to Mantova, Italy this weekend to attend the [literature festival](http://www.festivaletteratura.it) and I cannot find any accommodation. Inexpensive accommodation is fully booked and/or too far from the city center. I have also tried [Airbnb](http://www.airbnb.com) and [CouchSurfing](http://www.couchsurfing.org) with no luck.

I am currently considering spending the night roaming around, but it would be nice if there was some place that stays open all night (like a bookstore, diner, etc) ([manga kissa](http://www.unmissablejapan.com/sleeping/manga-kissa) in Mantova anyone? :-)) where I can spend some time recharging the laptop, rest the legs, sip some coffee. The place should be in downtown Mantova. I'd rather avoid pubs or disco, but I would consider them as a last resort.

Anyone know of such a place?

Comment: Verona can be a solution? last train from Mantova to Verona is at 20.28 and there are several accommodations near Verona Porta Nuova station.

Comment: @GuidoPreite ehm, not really, I'd like to stay somewhere downtown Mantova, as I wrote, because festival events end up late and I'll probably like to hang out with people after that. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Check out this [website](http://www.homestay.com/) for finding homestays. I did a quick search and there seems to be places available, but I don't know how far away they are from where you want to stay. I used this website to find cheap accommodation when I went to Tokyo recently and can highly recommend it.

Comment: @Geeo did you find anything? Possibly answer-worthy?

Comment: @MarkMayo totally forgot about this, thanks. Answer provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cheapest solution I've been able to find was the [Festival official camping ground](http://www.festivaletteratura.it/campeggio.php?lin=en&id=) (Italian only, sorry) which is a nice camping not so far from downtown Mantova. It's actually a 15 mins walking from almost every place in Mantova with an event associated to the festival.

The camping is provided with plenty of space to plant your tent, a common area where you can have your meals and recharge your phone/laptop/whatever batteries and toilets and showers with hot water.
The cost for one night is 5€, 15€ if you plan to stay all the 5 days the festival last. Parking the car is free of charge.